# Terminal and Eclipse displaying \n0000 differently

Tags: java, printing, null, char

Explained easily in pictures, kind of hard to do it in words:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUZal.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQUfH.png)

As you can see, in terminal, the print works fine. In eclipse, it won't print the next print statement if the preceding print value is `null`

Specific code:

```
for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex<COL; colIndex++)
{
    System.out.print(" "+board[rowIndex][colIndex]+" ");
    System.out.print("|");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use space instead to make the |s line up? Space is ASCII `32 (0x20)`.

Comment: yeah. I changed it to print a space if there is a nul char. I was just curious why this was happening.